# How to fade in box-shadow via jQuery addClass()

Tags: jquery, css

**UPDATED**

I have a div, .shadow-circle-lg:

```
<div class="shadow-circle-lg"></div>
```

I want to fade in a different border styling to the div, by adding another class, .circle-highlight:

```
.circle-highlight{
box-shadow: 
0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1),
0 0 0 10px rgba(188,190,192, 0.3);
 }
```

Result:

```
   <div class="shadow-circle-lg circle-highlight"></div>
```

I want this transition to fadeIn over 400ms.

I am trying solve this via a fadeIn animation with the function below:

```
$this.siblings('.user_icon').find('.shadow-circle-lg').addClass('circle-highlight').hide().fadeIn(400);
```

However, hiding the function this way first creates a "flash" effect as the original visible div disappears. I only want to fade in the box-shadow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats in `circle-highlight` rule? Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/z8pBJ/

Comment: FYI — for future reference, please break the statement into multiple lines when chaining jQuery calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use can use a simple `transition` attribute:

```
.circle-highlight {
    transition: box-shadow 400ms;
    box-shadow: 
        0 0 0  1px rgba(  0,  0,  0, 0.1),
        0 0 0 10px rgba(188,190,192, 0.3);
}
```

Then just add the class. Don't call `fadeIn`

```
$this.siblings('.user_icon')
        .find('.shadow-circle-lg')
        .addClass('circle-highlight');
```

See a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MTz8E/1/

UPDATE

For some of the not-so-new browsers (Firefox 4, Opera), this would likely work:

```
.circle-highlight {
       -moz-transition: box-shadow 400ms; /* Firefox 4 */
         -o-transition: box-shadow 400ms; /* Opera     */
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 400ms; /* Chrome    */
            transition: box-shadow 400ms;

    box-shadow: 
        0 0 0  1px rgba(  0,  0,  0, 0.1),
        0 0 0 10px rgba(188,190,192, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Would this work if I wanted cross-browser compatability with -webkit and -moz variants?

Comment: It's hard to say without trying them. I highly recommend that every web developer pull up their clients' sites at least once in those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[fadeIn's callback function](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#fadeIn-duration-easing-complete) may solve your problem.
 Try something like this :

```
$this.siblings('.user_icon').find('.shadow-circle-lg').fadeIn(400, function() { (this).addClass('circle-highlight') });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either; it has the same effect of adding the class without a slow fade transition.

Comment: ok sorry i haven't tested it. Try to use the callback function of `fadeIn` and put inside that function the code you need. that should do the stuff. I use this when i want to fadeIn/fadeOut something and do some actions on a object, and that always works perfectly !

Comment: I think this approach is trying to apply the fadeIn to the .find() node, not the circle-highlight; the latter is simply executed after fadeIn